# Python throwing error on np.array type for unidentifiable reason

Tags: python, typeerror

The following code:

```
import numpy as np


N=4
m=2**N

I=[0]*16
for j in range(m):
    I[j] = ("{0:04b}".format(j))

i = np.array([-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
ψ0 = np.array([1]*m)
HW = np.array([0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4])
sorted_i = np.array([x for _,x in sorted(zip(HW,i))])
sorted_I = np.array([x for _,x in sorted(zip(HW,I))])
```

when I hit 'run' gives

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-4e0f18a0df58> in <module>
     13 ψ0 = np.array([1]*m)
     14 HW = np.array([0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4])
---> 15 sorted_i = np.array([x for _,x in sorted(zip(HW,i))])
     16 sorted_I = np.array([x for _,x in sorted(zip(HW,I))])

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

However copy + pasting the exact same code and running it in isolation from a separate jupyter notebook file gives no errors. What on Earth is causing this? I thought it might be vestiges of variable names messing things up but I have no idea.

Comment: What do you get if you add the following: `print(np.array, sorted, zip)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `np` might have been assigned to a different object, try restarting your Jupyter notebook, you could also try a different alias for `numpy` like `import numpy as npy`

Comment: After restarting the kernel the same error occured; somehow restarting it from within the jupyter notebook itself seemed to fix it though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

means that you tried to `__call__`, that means using an object `f` with the sintax `f(x)` a 'numpy.ndarray' object, but such an object cannot be used with that sintax, as it does not make sense to want to use an array as a function.

Your error almost surely comes from the fact that `sorted` and or `zip` have been shadowed and now contain a numpy array instead of the built-in function